# ASP.NET session timeout during long running request

Tags: asp.net, http, session-timeout

I have an app which has as session timeout of an hour. however, I want the user to be able to upload huge files which may take much more than this so I have set the execution timeout to 1 day (i.e. larger than the session timeout).

Am I guaranteed by ASP.NET that the session won't time out during a long-running request? I have tested this and it seems to work OK, but of course there are a number of possible environmental factors which could cause it to work in my test environment but not other deployment scenarios

Answer (score 0):

If you set it to 1 day (24 hours) then the session will be good for that long. Session will reset when you do:

IISReset

Recycle App Pool

Be careful, everyone's session will be that long if you do this. If your site has heavy usage, you will have memory problems. Session is stored in the server it self. Also, you could have the option to extend the users session on the "upload page" and only users on that page will have a long session. Once upload is done, you could end the session, keeping it a little cleaner.

Comment: The question is specifically about when the execution timeout is much larger than the session timeout.  This answer doesn't seem to address that.